# AWS on Terraform - can't change SSH port via user data (Linux Kali)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terraform

Working with Terraform 0.12v and the AWS provider.

I'm using `user_data` in order to open an SSH connection on port `8080`.

My resources.tf:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  user_data = "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"
  #user_data = "${file("init.sh")}" <--also did not work

  ami           = "ami-06fea6d88c62d4e26" #Update: The problem is probably related to this ami (Linux Kali)
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public_subnet.id}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.public_sg.id}"]
  key_name = "${var.auth_key_name}"
}


data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("./init.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    ssh_port = "8080"
  }
}
```

init.tpl:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo sed -i 's/22/${ssh_port}/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

**The problem: I can't connect with** `ssh -i "my-key.pem" ec2-user@<instance-ip> -p 8080` (**connection refused**).

---

#### Debugging

In order to debug, I opened port `22` and SSH-ed into the EC2 instance.

When I run from inside: `ec2-user@kali:~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I can see that the port wasn't change:

```
Port 22 <------- This was supposed to be 8080
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
.
.
.
```

A few more points:

1) This is not a typo in the `sed` command because when I run from inside of the EC2 instance:

```
sudo sed -i 's/22/8080/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

It works perfectly.

2) I can also see in the AWS management console that the two lines of the `init.tpl` appear under `user_data` (and that `${ssh_port}` is changed to `8080`).

3) I also tried to write the `ssh_port` inline as `8080` in order to use an regular `init.sh` script instead of `init.tpl` - still not working.

4) **Important Update - The problem is probably related to the ami I chose (Linux Kali) , because when I changed to Amazon Linux 2 AMI (ami-0ce933e2ae91880d3) everything works great**.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

---

#### Additional related files.

security-group.tf:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg" {
  name        = "public_sg"
  description = "Allow specific ports only"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.base_vpc.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = "8080"
    to_port     = "8080"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

}
```

providers.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
  shared_credentials_file = ".credentials"
}
```

Full content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ec2-user@kali:~$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PasswordAuthentication no
ClientAliveInterval 180
```

---

I found the following related threads:

[Running ssh on Amazon EC2 instance on port other than 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475303/running-ssh-on-amazon-ec2-instance-on-port-other-than-22)

[Running EC2 instance suddenly refuses SSH connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026148/running-ec2-instance-suddenly-refuses-ssh-connection/21563478#21563478)

[Commands in user_data are not executed in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882030/commands-in-user-data-are-not-executed-in-terraform)

But haven't found a solution.

Comment: What does the cloud-init logs say? Is it erroring during the apt upgrade?